# Increase the maximum daily flag allowance/review allowances if you have access to the moderator tools

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, 10k-tools, limits

I understand obviously why the flag allowance is in place, to prevent users from "spamming" flags on a daily basis.

My question is, if a user hits the 10k mark and gets access to the Moderator tools, shouldn't they have at least a higher flag allowance, if not an *unlimited* allowance? It makes sense as we actually now have the power to review/invalidate flags. Using that review page can pretty much max you out in a matter of minutes.

The same also applies for the reviewing process (think it's capped at 20 every 12 hours at the moment?

Comment: Your flag allowance does increase with rep. There's just no "step" at 10k.

Comment: You get an additional flag ever 2k of reputation, as well as for having a history of raising helpful flags. No need to raise flags for 10k.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Seems relatively small though, don't you think?

Comment: @mattytommo: Nope, I don't think.

Comment: The more privileges I've gained, the less need I've found for flags. I flag far less than before.

Comment: The restrictions aren't just in place to stop you from spamming the flag queue. They're also there to:

  1. Stop you flagging lots of posts incorrectly. You (or I) can only cause limited damage.
  2. Give you some time off.
  3. Allow other people a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Unlimited*?

I'd say that's a bad idea. It doesn't take any special magic to get to 10,000 reputation. While we expect that someone who sticks around long enough to get that much reputation would learn to understand how the site works (assuming they didn't "get it" at first) there's no guarantee of such a thing.

Imagine how much mischief someone could get into with unlimited flags before someone could stop them and how much clean up *others* would need to undertake. Maybe that's not such a risk at Stack Overflow where certainly *someone* will notice the shenanigans in relatively short order, imagine how bad it could be on a site with a smaller population.

Comment: Whilst I agree, I did say *possibly unlimited*. I was more leaning towards just an increase in the limit.